# Postfix Relay Server

Tags: postfix, email-server

There are two aws instances A and B.

A is setup up as a mail server by following this article: https://www.tecmint.com/setup-postfix-mail-server-in-ubuntu-debian/
It is working fine, and now if someone sends mail to `dhruv@mymail.com` it is received over A and can be viewed from anywhere via `<A's-IP-Address>/squirrelmail`.

Now, I need to setup B as a relay server such that all the mails first arrive at B and then B sends them to A.

I have been reading a lot of articles like: https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/smtp-relay-between-2-postfix-smtp-servers
All these articles create a `sasl_passwd` file which contains the username and password.
Is there any way to do this without creating this file either in plain text or in hash ?

Another query is: Is the term relay server correct for what I am trying to do ?

Comment: could it be that you want to create an backup mx?

Comment: backup mx would mean that the mail can go to either A or B right ? I want that mail must always arrive at B and then B would send it to A.

Comment: i belive that you not exactly knows what's your need, sofar superuser is the right place. no the backup mx get in place by dns in case of the primary is out of order, maybe you want a relayhost

Comment: ok will post on superuser.